# Disable "Tap to Click" on Dell Inspiron 1525 running Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, touchpad

After my install of Windows 7, Dell Quickset will not download.  I used quickset to disable tap to click in Vista. The download from the official dell site starts as a DellDriverDownload application, and then says I have no applications to download.

I have tried synaptics, yet the "Tap to Click" toggle is greyed out and unclickable.

Any suggestions for other drivers/fixes?

Thanks

**Answer:** The answer was to download the "pointing stick" driver from [Dell Support](http://support.dell.com/support/). Thanks to outsideblasts for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same machine here. I didn't install the full quickset, only the touchpad driver. In the drivers page for 1525, look for "Input devices", then the second of the three items: "Dell driver- touchpad/pointing stick". The driver number is R176423.exe. Works well and "Tap to Click" can be disabled through control panel.

Comment: Thank you. I think I found my problem: the Dell Download Manager Application Manager is not compatible with Google Chrome. I tried it in Firefox and it worked well. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I just installed the 64-bit Dell input driver R244796 on the Dell Inspiron 1525, and the scrolling does work. This should work for Windows Vista and 7 64-bit. Here's the link to download:

> http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R244796&SystemID=STUDIO1737&servicetag=&os=WV64&osl=en&deviceid=16519&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=4&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=17&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=354879

Answer (score 0):

OK I found an answer and thought I would share it here. I found this post at the dell support forum and decided to try it and it works!!! My tap click is disabled!! I am soo happy!

> Here is the Alps driver from the
>   Vostro 1720 for Windows 7. This is
>   what I am using and it works just
>   fine.

[link](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=22&l=en&s=dfh&releaseid=R227995&SystemID=VOS_N_1720&servicetag=&os=W764&osl=en&deviceid=16519&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=2&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=1&libid=17&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&fileid=327208)